# How do you make it so there is newline at the end of a file while reading it in C++?

Tags: c++

I wrote this program that has a guide, but when it prints out the guide, it outputs:

```
guideWould you like to run this program again (y/n):
```

But what I want it to output is:

```
guide
Would you like to run this program again (y/n):
```

Note that the guide part comes from a file, not a cout statement.
My code looks like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    // Declare the variables and arrays
    int varNum = 1;
    int totVar = 0;
    int choice = 0;
    int userNums[1000] = {};
    double ch1 = 0;
    double ch2 = 0;
    double total = 0;
    double avg = 0;
    string sym = "";
    char dec = 'y';


    //Ask the user for their choice and then record it
    cout << "6) Guide \n";
    cout << "Your choice: ";
    cin >> choice;


                } else if(choice == 6){
                    ifstream f("guide.txt");

                    if (f.is_open())
                    cout << f.rdbuf();

                }
    cout << "Would you like to run this program again? (y/n): ";
    cin >> dec;
    if(dec == 'y') return main();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What does the code look like? You should add it. All it seems like you need to do is add a new line.

Comment: Can do anything without your code. Please post your code.

Comment: Can't correct code we cannot see. [MCVE] please.

Comment: I put the code above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming your print statement looks something like:

```
cout << "guide";
cout << "Would you like to run this program again (y/n):";
```

If you want to include a newline in between "guide" and "Would", all you need to do is include a `\n` or use `endl` like so:

```
cout << "guide\n";
cout << "Would you like to run this program again (y/n):";
```

or alternatively

```
cout << "guide" << endl;
cout << "Would you like to run this program again (y/n):";
```

EDIT:

All you need to do is the `\n` right before the "Would you like to run this program again (y/n):" so that it looks like this `cout << "\nWould you like to run this program again (y/n):";`

Comment: No, the guide part comes from a file.

Comment: Can you edit the file or post some of your code? It's tough to know exactly what you mean without some source code

Comment: Ok, I will do that.

Comment: I edited my answer to hopefully give you a solution.

Comment: `std::endl` isn't an alternative to `'\n'`. It's different, and shouldn't be used if you don't need the extra stuff that it does.

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
std::cout << "guide" << std::endl << "Would you like to run this program again (y/n):";
```

or

```
printf("guide\nWould you like to run this program again (y/n):");
```

Comment: You could place a newline in the second string, "\nWould", which would eliminate the need for `std::endl`.

Comment: Prefer to use `'\n'` over `std::endl`. Forcing a flush is usually superfluous (as streams will auto flush when they need to) and can lead to inefficient code (because flushing too often is an inefficient use of resources).